# Type checking in separate function not working in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, validation, types, typeerror

I'm validating type of parameter in separate function but still it is giving the following Error-

`Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

The code is like this-

```
function paramValidator(param?: string){
  if(param===undefined){
    throw new Error('parameter missing');
  }
}
function xyz(a: string){
  console.log(a);
}

function abc(a?: string){
  try{
    paramValidator(a);
    // Working Fine
    // if(a===undefined){
    //   throw new Error('parameter missing');
    // }
    xyz(a);  //This line is throwing error
  }
  catch(e){
    console.log('Error');
  }
  
}
```

I want to put validation logics in a separate function for cleaner code. How to enforce that the parameter is defined after validation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Typescript 3.7+, use you use [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions). The change is minimal; you simply add an `asserts` condition to your method signature:

```
function paramValidator(param?: string): asserts params is string {
```

Any time after you have called this function, Typescript will recognise that the value of param should be `string`, and you won't get the error.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwIYCdUFsBqqA2MAJqlHOgBRqZYD8AXIgM5ToxgDmAlI6k0wFN0UJigzZEMUSzadEAbwBQiScCrisAXm3giA4OwFEuSlSqgALdHADuiMALsBRdNcoByatgFQhiLFJM7BzuXADcyogAvooxoJCwCIgAHgCeAF4UqIwywSaREAhMcPgCAHT4cBxZ4bGKivHQ8EioAEYQWQzMrHmmiKypfSpeuATEpOQ1EWaIAPSziADq5ADWwYgAYoaRKvOqWdqauvqGxkNzC+ZWtvaOiC5uFJ4aPn4B-MGh02Z7MTNpmVQ4V2swAKhYpIhCA5JKJLNYbOshG5In9EBBSBALBQBPkZoUwMVShUqk8HuQvqjIrEgA)

Answer (score 3):

You can return true if the param is actually a string and use this as condition

```
function paramValidator(param?: string): param is string {
  if(param===undefined){
    throw new Error('parameter missing');
  }
  return true;
}

function xyz(a: string){
  console.log(a);
}

function abc(a?: string){
  try{
    if (paramValidator(a)) {
        xyz(a);
    }
  }
  catch(e){
    console.log('Error');
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not want if conditions. The whole purpose of creating separate parameter validation function is to reduce if conditions. btw I found the solution and have written in the answer. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

It is because of you using`?` optional operator which tells the function that it might be available during the execution that is based on whether you send it in the `abc` function or not. So, it becomes `undefined` till the time method is not called with that param.

For such cases, you assign a fallback i.e default parameters values in the methods. I'm not sure why you need to have validator if you can default assign values, it is good to have empty string instead something is undefined.

```
function paramValidator(param?: string){
  if(param===undefined){
    throw new Error('parameter missing');
  }
}
function xyz(a: string){
  console.log(a);
}

function abc(a: string = ''){
  try{
    paramValidator(a);  // now you don't need to call it 
    // Working Fine
    // if(a===undefined){
    //   throw new Error('parameter missing');
    // }
    xyz(a);  //This line is throwing error
  }
  catch(e){
    console.log('Error');
  }
  
}
```

Also, when you have objects and properties associated with it try to check their properties using [??](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/nullish-coalescing-the-operator-in-typescript#:%7E:text=TypeScript%203.7%20added%20support%20for,might%20be%20null%20or%20undefined%20.) to set null|undefined properties to default values, so you won't expect any undesirable behaviour in the application.

Comment: @Apporva I'm using thrift+grpc in node.js. It automatically generates the function definition. We can't assign default values to the parameters.  Btw I found the solution and have written in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use `xyz(a!)` as it will enforce that the parameter is defined. We have already validated the type in another function, so we do not need to do that while calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

I think putting your try catch block inside a if  block will fix the error .Because param validator waiting a string and you are passing  a possible undefined or string value to it .

```js
function abc(a?: string){
if(a){
    try{
        paramValidator(a);
        // Working Fine
        // if(req.a===undefined){
        //   throw new Error('parameter missing');
        // }
        xyz(a);  //This line is throwing error
      }
      catch(e){
        console.log('Error');
      }
    }
  
}
```

Comment: It will fix but that is a validation itself using if condition. I want to validate the request in separate function. In your code, you are doing that redundantly.

Comment: I saw now. But the error is originating from xyz function. Cant you use it  as `function xyz(a?:string){   console.log(a);
 } `   ?

Comment: I can't change the xyz function definition because a is a required variable in that function.  Btw I found the solution and have written in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As [Aprova Chikara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7025699/apoorva-chikara) described, It was a good explanation and outstanding solution for your problem. But if you would like insist in your code and wouldn't change its structure yet, You can keep your base code as follows with 2 tiny changes:

```
function paramValidator(param?: string):string{
   if(param===undefined){
       throw new  Error("parameter missing");
   }
   return param;// 1
}

function xyz(a: string){
   console.log(a);
}

function abc(a?: string){
  try{
    a = paramValidator(a) // 2
    xyz(a);  //Now, this line is not throwing error!
  }
  catch(e){
    console.log('Error');
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Majid. You solution will work. But I found a better solution and have written that as my answer. You can check that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Required keyword in TS](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype), like `Required<T>` for your xyz func.

```
type IParamValidatorParam = string | undefined;

function paramValidator(param: IParamValidatorParam){
  if(param === undefined){
    throw new Error('parameter missing');
  }
}
function xyz(a: Required<IParamValidatorParam>){
  console.log(a);
}

function abc(a: IParamValidatorParam){
  try{
    paramValidator(a);
    // Working Fine
    // if(a===undefined){
    //   throw new Error('parameter missing');
    // }
    xyz(a: Required<IParamValidatorParam>);  //This line won't throw any error
  }
  catch(e){
    console.log('Error');
  }
}
```

However, please make sure that you validate all the function params carefully before making the use of Required keyword.